# Show embed YouTube player's progress bar when auto hide

Tags: youtube

YouTube change their player to black style.

When you watching a video on YouTube website, the player bar will disappear when you mouse out the player, but still keep the progress bar, like this:
[image: Still show progress bar when player bar hide]

So I try to embed the video on web page, but when I set **autohide=1**, the player bar totally gone, include progress bar.

Have any idea to do that like on youtube website?

```
<object width="425" height="349">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?autohide=1&enablejsapi=1&iv_load_policy=3&version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="349" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

### Updated 2011-10-28

I set autohide to **3** (not be mentioned at Youtube player document), that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the iframe option instead?

Test putting autohide after enablejsapi?

Or test out autohide=2 (default option) to see if that brings it back, then try change it again.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#autohide

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already solve this problem. I set autohide to 3, the option not appear inside Youtube player document.