# Embedded YT on mobile: autohide=0&controls=1 but controls invisible

Tags: youtube-api

When embedding a video with [autohide=0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autohide) and [controls=1 (which is default anyway)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls), one would assume the controls are always visible.

This is however not the case when looking at an embedded video on Android or iOS, where the exact same embed code yields a player without "always-on" controls (e.g. before clicking "play").

[I've created a small demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9207036/dude-where-are-my-controls.html) which indeed has YT display the controls when viewed on desktop, but not when viewed on iOS or Android.

My questions:

- Is this a bug (and if so; is a solution in the works)?
- Is there another way to force the controls to be visible on mobile?

Comment: The autohide works only for full screen. Are you trying it out for full screen ?

Comment: No, but the problem is specific for mobile display, where bottom controls aren't consistently shown even with autohide=0.

Comment: I see a bug filed here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3807 But it seems more related to flash than mobile - but you could take a look at it - looks like its a little broken - there's an interesting answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021714/show-embed-youtube-players-progress-bar-when-auto-hide

Comment: Intersting, thanks Slartibartfast. I think the problem in the case of the missing controls is that YouTube assumes that behavior for mobile can (and should) be different. I think this is perfectly acceptable for "default" usage, but not so much when ignoring specifc options set using the iframe api. Eagerly awaiting someone from YT to collect the bounty by providing a good answer here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

iOS Safari supports HTML5 video (it uses Quicktime to render it). Behind the scenes, the YouTube API is creating an HTML5 video element inside its iframe. There is no HTML5 attribute that specifies whether or not to keep the controls visible, therefore YouTube cannot make the controls stay visible on the iOS.

Unfortunately, at this time, I think the only solution is to build your controls and use the javascript DOM API to control the video.